# MongoDB facet, ignore filters

Tags: mongodb, facet

Given the following dataset, I want to add facet aggregation but I want the count ignore the filter
For example, I want to facet on 'tag', but if I apply a filter on tag, I should still see all available tag on collection, regarding the other filter (price, or date for ex)

```
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "The Pillars of Society", "artist" : "Grosz", "year" : 1926,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("199.99"),
  "tags" : [ "painting", "satire", "Expressionism", "caricature" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "title" : "Melancholy III", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1902,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("280.00"),
  "tags" : [ "woodcut", "Expressionism" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "title" : "Dancer", "artist" : "Miro", "year" : 1925,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("76.04"),
  "tags" : [ "oil", "Surrealism", "painting" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "title" : "The Great Wave off Kanagawa", "artist" : "Hokusai",
  "price" : NumberDecimal("167.30"),
  "tags" : [ "woodblock", "ukiyo-e" ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "title" : "The Persistence of Memory", "artist" : "Dali", "year" : 1931,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("483.00"),
  "tags" : [ "Surrealism", "painting", "oil" ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "title" : "Composition VII", "artist" : "Kandinsky", "year" : 1913,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("385.00"),
  "tags" : [ "oil", "painting", "abstract" ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "title" : "The Scream", "artist" : "Munch", "year" : 1893,
  "tags" : [ "Expressionism", "painting", "oil" ] }
{ "_id" : 8, "title" : "Blue Flower", "artist" : "O'Keefe", "year" : 1918,
  "price" : NumberDecimal("118.42"),
  "tags" : [ "abstract", "painting" ] }
```

Here is my query

```
db.artwork.aggregate( [
  {
    {$match: criteria}
    $facet: {
      "categorizedByTags": [
        { $unwind: "$tags" },
        { $sortByCount: "$tags" }
      ],
    }
  }
])
```

My problem is, when the user check, for example, 'painting' tag, the facet contains only 'painting', then he should uncheck painting to see all tags and check another one, then it's impossible for the client to check many filter.

How can I ignore tag filter in facet building ?

Comment: can you show example filter input for your all possible cases.

Comment: sure, possible filters are {year: Number, tag: [String], price: Number}

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: If I filter on a tag (let's say painting), I wan to get only artworks with this tag, but, still see all facets

Comment: after $unwind stage do `$match` stage with your condition for tags.

Comment: @barden: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the exact same question. I would like to avoid a second database call...